# python web scraping Weatherforecast

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python(actually second time I try to learn the language so i know a little something) and I'm trying to build a script that scrapes the weather forecast.

Now i have a little problem with finding the right html classes to import into python. I have this code now:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://openweathermap.org/city/2743477")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
city_name = soup.find(class_="weather-widget__city-name")
print(city_name)
```

Problem is that this just returns 'None'

I found the class that the code searches for via chrome and inspect page. If i export the html page through python with the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://openweathermap.org/city/2743477")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
city_name = soup.find(class_="weather-widget__city-name")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Then I see the html page in cmd(as expected) but I'm also unable to find 'class_="weather-widget__city-name"' so I'm not amazed that python is also unable to. My question is, why is the html code that python gives me different than the html code Chrome shows on the site? And am I doing something wrong with trying to find the weather widget through BeautifulSoup this way?

Here is a picture from the page, the part that I'm trying to scrape is circled in red.

[Screenshot from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIejp.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That site is loaded with JS.

Python requests doesn't activate those scripts. One of those scripts is responsible for loading the data you are looking for (you can see it's JS, maybe with a bit jQuery I didn't actually check, by the spinning circle while it's loading).

My suggestion here is use the sites [API](https://openweathermap.org/api).

I am not subscribed to the site so I can't show here an example but the trick is simple. You subscribe to the sites API with the basic (and free) plan, get an API key and start sending get requests to the API URLs.
This will also simplify things for you further since you wouldn't need BeautifulSoup for the parsing. The responses are all in JSON.

There is another nastier way around it and that is using [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). This module will simulate the web browser and all of it's JS activating, HTML rendering, CSS loading mechanisms.

I have experience with both and I strongly recommend sticking to the API (if that option exists).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have looked into the API but didn't get this one to work(I have signed up but there are only a few request per hour allowed so I couldn't test enough to my liking). On the other hand I tried another api from ISS and that works like a charm. So for the future I would definitely look into API's more.

Answer (score 0):

For sites that use JS to send further requests, after we request the initial URL, one method that can work is to study the network tab of Chrome's developer tools (or the equivalent in any other browser).

You'll usually find a big list of URLs being requested by the browser. Most of them are unnecessary for our purposes. And few of them relate to other sites such as Google, Facebook.

In this particular case, after the initial URL is requested, you'll find a few '.js' files being retrieved and after that, three scripts (forecast, weather, daily) that correspond to the data which finally gets presented by the browser.

From those three, the data you ask for comes from the 'weather' script. If you click on it in the network tab, another side pane will open which will contain header information, preview, etc.

In the Headers tab, you'll find the URL that you need to use, which is:

```
https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2743477&units=metric&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1
```

The `b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1` might be a general API key that is assigned to a browser request. I don't know for sure. But all we need to know is that it doesn't change. I've tried on two different systems and this value doesn't change.

The `2743477` is, of course, the City ID. You can download a reference of various cities and their IDs in their site itself:

http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/

As nutmeg64 said, the site actually responds with a JSON file. That's the case with both the API and the request of this URL found in the network tab of a browser.

As for the codes appearing in the JSON, the site gives you a reference to the codes and their meanings:

https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions

With this information, you can use `requests` and `json` to retrieve and manipulate the data. Here's a sample script:

```
from pprint import pprint
import json

import requests

city_id = 2743477
url = 'https://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={}&units=metric&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1'.format(city_id)

req_headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Host': 'openweathermap.org',
    'Referer': 'https://openweathermap.org/city/2743477',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url, headers=req_headers)

d = json.loads(r.text)
pprint(d)
```

However, as nutmeg64 said, it's better to use the API, and resist the temptation to bombard the site with more requests than you truly need.

You can find all about their API here:

https://openweathermap.org/current

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I have tried the code and it really helped me understand how this site was build, and I am certain I can use this technique for future reference

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium in combination with BeautifulSoup to get any of the table from that page with no hardship. Here is how you can do:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://openweathermap.org/city/2743477")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.quit()
table_tag = soup.select(".weather-widget__items")[0]
tab_data = [[item.text.strip() for item in row_data.select("td")]
                for row_data in table_tag.select("tr")]

for data in tab_data:
    print(data)
```

Partial result:

```
['Wind', 'Gentle Breeze,\n        3.6 m/s, Southwest ( 220 )']
['Cloudiness', 'Broken clouds']
['Pressure', '1014 hpa']
['Humidity', '100 %']
['Sunrise', '11:53']
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice!! I'm definitely going to look into it!!